# On Windows, how to make VSCode play nicely with pnpm through WSL

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, pnpm

I have a project that uses `pnpm` for dependency management. Some of the code requires the code be run on a Unix like system. Using WSL allows all scripts to work perfectly.

**However, VSCode will not be able to resolve modules.**

[image]

I have updated the settings to ensure `pnpm` is used by VSCode. This doesn't help.

[image: Settings]

Installing dependencies with `pnpm` without WSL resolves the VSCode errors but unfortunately this doesn't help because then scripts fail to run.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Run vscode remotely from wsl

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade WSL version to v1 helps for me

```
wsl --set-version 1
```

After this just remove every node_modules folders from your project(s) and run `pnpm install`